# Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I'm trying to install Realm for Swift via Cocoapods.

First what I did was **pod init** into my project
Then I open podfile and changed it like this:

```
target 'Taskio' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'RealmSwift'

end
```

Then I closed podfile and execute command **pod install**

Everything pass good. But now when i opened workspace I'm getting error while importing RealmSwift

Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift'

[image: Error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly try to check what workspace you open after cocoapods were install open **App.xcworkspace** file.If yes open Pods directory and check if file is actually installed by manually navigation to **REALM** folder. After navigation to this [article](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2885) it is possible to conclude that you should:

> New project -> build&run -> add realm via cocoapods -> open Xcode
>   workspace -> build&run again = success

Comment: Yes, I'm opening App.xcworkspace, yes realm is installed

Answer (score 7):

Once you have installed RealmSwift pod.

**Step.1** you should open your project by double click on **your_project_name.xcworkspace** file.

**Step.2** Go to project settings --> Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries --> Add framework "RealmSwift.framework" as shown below

[image]

That it!!

Now you can import the module

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I think I had the same problem with ObjectMapper Framework. What I did is just opened myapp.xcworkspace and press command + b. All things worked fine after this. Strange error in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

**xCode version:** Version 9.0 (9A235)

**Mac OS High Sierra:** 10.13.1 Beta (17B25c)

1. Close xCode
2. Delete Pods Folder and Podfile.lock

[image: Cannot load underlying module for 'RealmSwift']

3. In the terminal run a "pod install" after cd'ing into the project directory.
4. Open xCode and Build Project.

Good Luck!