# Unable to archive iOS app after updating to Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, realm

I'm having problems archiving an iOS Swift application since the last Xcode update (Xcode 7.3), the application builds and runs correctly in debug mode but as soon as I try to archive it I get the following error:

```
No such module "RealmSwift"
```

Although it references `RealmSwift` it fails randomly importing this or any other pod.

The most strange point is that downgrading to Xcode 7.2.1 and Command Line tools 7.2 doesn't fix the problem.

I've clean Cocoapods cache, completely removed `~/Library/Developer` folder, removed my `Pods` folder within the project folder. Even trying to archive with a different machine doesn't work. I rolled back to a version of the app released on Crashlytics and therefore successfully archived in the past with the same result.

Any thoughts about what could be wrong?

Comment: Hey AngryDuck, that's what I thought at first but after reinstalling everything and even trying on a different laptop I'm still getting the same problem...

Comment: this thread looks pretty good man http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216735/cannot-load-underlying-module-for-realmswift

Comment: Yeah, I already tried all the things described there with no luck.

Comment: i dont think so but you can try by Pod install and build your project.

Comment: What version of Realm are you on? There were some build issues when Xcode 7.3 came out, but they should have all been fixed in Realm 0.98.6.

Comment: Hi TiM, I'm on 0.98.6

Comment: Did you try running ```pod install``` again after updating to Xcode 7.3?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what else to recommend then. I guess as one last thing to try, there's a CocoaPods plugin called deintegrate that completely removes CocoaPods from a project (including restoring the Xcode project settings). https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate It might be worth completely removing CocoaPods from your project with that and trying again from scratch.