# Getting error "Cannot load underlying module" when importing Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, module-map

I have written a framework in Swift 2.3 that uses Cocoapods to utilize a few Objective-C projects such as AFNetworking and CocoaLumberjack. Since bridging headers cannot be used in frameworks I have defined module maps for each Objective-C project (as well as for a few objective-c utiltities I have written). For example, the module.modulemap for AFNetworkModule looks like:

```
module AFNetworkModule {
  header "../../Pods/Headers/Public/AFNetworking/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.h"
  export *
}
```

Also added the path to modulemaps in the Build Settings -> Import Paths.
This way I can import the modules in my framework swift code:

```
import AFNetworkModule
```

The setting Defines Module is set to Yes in the Build Settings for the framework.

Externally I can use the framework without any problems in my sample Swift app using `import MyFramework` **when both the framework and the sample app are in the same workspace**:

```
-- SampleAppProj
-- MyFrameworkProj
-- Pods
```

But I get "**Cannot load underlying module for MyFramework**" when trying to import the framework in a separate Swift project. The generated framework contains a Headers folder containing MyFramework-Swift.h and MyFramework.h (the umbrella file). I have not added any headers to the umbrella file as I am using modules to import objective-c internally in the swift framework.

Comment: If you're using cocoapods, it automatically creates modules for your pods, so I'm confused why you need to create module maps. Can you explain that part in more detail?

Comment: When you use Objective-C pods in a Swift project, as this case, you also use the bridging header to include the header files but bridging header is not allowed in frameworks. The only way I know is using module maps. Would be great to know if there are other options.

Comment: You shouldn't need a bridging header to include the header files, you just need to import the framework that the pod defines, like `import AFNetworking`. Is cocoapods generating frameworks for you? I assume you have `use_frameworks!` in your Podfile?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot have `use_frameworks!` in my Podfile due to other issues (related to use of a google api in the podfile).

Comment: Also, apart from how the module maps are created, it looks like `import MyFramework` in the sample app makes the framework accessible if the sample app is in the same workspace but not if imported in a separate project. Any way to know what "underlying module" Xcode cannot load?

Comment: You can look at the full build logs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014359/how-do-i-view-the-full-build-log-on-xcode5 and see if that gives you any insight.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the link.

Comment: @daveWeston, you could add `use_frameworks!` as an answer, and I'll gladly upvote it. It worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem suddenly popping up regarding the AVFoundation module, on an app that was perfectly compiling till then.
As a workaround, unchecking `Show live issues` in `Xcode -> Settings -> General` allows to avoid this error and to compile.

Edit: Adding the module to the project settings fixed the issue. See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216735/cannot-load-underlying-module-for-realmswift).