# Cannot load underlying module for 'SceneKit'

Tags: swift, xcode, import, scenekit

I'm trying to run SceneKit in Xcode, but when I connect my physical device (iPhone 11) the import of SceneKit fails and the following error occurs: *"Cannot load underlying module for 'SceneKit'"*. Can anybody give me a hint how to fix that? Import of UIKit and ARKit seems to work normally, and even SceneKit before connection to physical device worked.

- HW: MacBook Air M1 2020
- OS: macOS Ventura Version 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)
- Xcode: Version 14.3 (14E222b)

connected with

- iPhone 11
- iOS-Version: 16.4.1 (a)

Already tried to reset the path to command-line tools via `sudo xcode-select --reset` and `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and also tried to delete all files in "DerivedData" but even after restart and rebuild no progress.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're using SceneKit with CocoaPods, right?

Comment: I installed CocoaPods for another project, but I'm not using it in the specific AR project with SceneKit. Does the CocoaPods-installation in the backgrund cause conflicts with SceneKit? How can I figure it out?

Comment: It's hard to say. For the purity of the experiment, try creating a SceneKit project on another computer, and then install CocoaPods. If the effect will be the same, then the problem is in the pods.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497003/getting-error-cannot-load-underlying-module-when-importing-swift-framework/76399418#76399418

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with SpriteKit module.
I tried a lot of troubleshooting solutions like:

- Cleaning the Build folder;
- Restarting Xcode;
- Reinstalling Xcode (!);
- Deleting contents of Xcode's Derived Data folder.

Nothing worked  But I believe I found the solution! ☺️

**Here's the fix that worked for me:**
Simply delete Xcode cached data.

**To delete Xcode cached data:**

1. Close Xcode;
2. Open **System Preferences** on you Mac;
3. Go to **General** tab and select **Storage** section;
4. Locate **Developer** section (the system might take few moments to calculate the size of the files on the drive);
5. Press on 'i' icon next to **Developer** section;
6. Under "Xcode Project Build Files" locate cache list item (I already deleted it, so I don't remember the original name  )
7. Delete the cache and wait for the deletion process to complete;
8. Open Xcode. You're good to go!

This worked for me.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but also deleting "Project Build Data and Indexes" in the same menu seems to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by deleting Derived Data.

1. Xcode -> Settings
2. Press arrow button near Derived Data -> it will open folder where Derived Data is located
3. Close Xcode
4. Remove all files in Derived Data folder

That's it!

[image: Xcode -> Settings]

Comment: The question specifically states that they tried to delete derived data and it didn't help. So this answer doesn't solve the issue in the question.